# Multiple Comparisons with Different Tests

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have a couple of categorical variables, representing two characteristics, I will call them A and B, so that X1 is either A or not A (0/1) and X2 is either B or not B (0/1). In addition, I have many dependent variables, some continuous and some categorical, all representing blood test results (red blood count, white blood count, etc...). I wish to perform a t-test (or Wilcoxon) for each continuous variables (vs. X1 and then vs. X2), and a Chi-Square or Fisher's Exact for each categorical. I have a couple of questions: 1. Is my analysis correct? 2. I am aware of the alpha issue, with having too many tests, and I am aware of FDR. What is the best way of handling this? Should I take the P-Values and calculate adjusted P-Values? Which formula should I use, and are my tests independent or dependent? Thank you.